# Как разбить строку на символы и числа?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Дана последовательность (-1.2+3.0)+2-8/6.
Надо разбить строку на символы и числа.
Как нужно отредактировать этот шаблон? Мне нужно, чтобы число с минусом перед ним считалось отрицательным, только если оно стоит первым в выражении. Сейчас же получается -1.2 и -8 (а не - и 8).

```
^-?\\d+\\.?\\d*|[-+*/()]
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения не подходят для правильного разбора арифметических выражений.

Пишите нормальный парсер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой ответ желателен для `3+(-1 + 2)`: `-1` или `-`, `1`? Я думаю, что `-1`, даже если `-1` не "стоит первым в выражении". Если скобки ограничивают "выражение", т.е. `(-1)` всегда интерпретируется как `-1`, а не (`-`, `1`), то формально уже нельзя распознать выражение с помощью "регулярного выражения", если скобки могут быть вложены произвольное количество раз, например: `4 + (-3 + (-1 + 2))`. Хотя фактически многие regex библиотеки поддерживают рекурсивный синтаксис, вот [пример, как распознать выражения во вложенных скобках](https://stackoverflow.com/a/562729).

Существует много примеров как математические выражения распарсить, например, [hoc калькулятор](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sources/plan9/sys/src/cmd/hoc/), описанный в книге ["Unix. Программное окружение" Роб Пайк, Брайн Керниган](http://www.symbol.ru/alphabet/82361.html).